# type or namespace definition, or end of file expected; "}" expected errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, calculator

```
namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program calc = new Program();
            Program validate = new Program();
        bool valid = true;

        while (valid == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Supported functions are *, /, +, -, ^, %.");
            Console.WriteLine("If you would like to find the greater number separate the numbers with a '?'");
            String userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            valid = validate.ValEntry(userInput);

            Console.WriteLine(calc.Calculate(userInput));
        }/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


       private string Calculate(string input)
        {
        int opstringloc = findoperator(input);
        int firstval = int.Parse(input.Substring(0, opstringloc));
        int secondval = int.Parse(input.Substring(0, opstringloc));
        char operation = Convert.ToChar(input.Substring(opstringloc));


            switch (operation)
            {
                case '+':
                    return Convert.ToString(firstval+secondval);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    return Convert.ToString(firstval-secondval);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    return Convert.ToString(firstval/secondval);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    return Convert.ToString(firstval*secondval);
                    break;
                case '%':
                    return Convert.ToString(firstval%secondval);
                    break;
                case '^':
                    return Convert.ToString(firstval^secondval);
                    break;
                case '?':
                    if (firstval<secondval)
                    {
                        return ("[0] < [1]"); Convert.ToString(firstval); Convert.ToString(secondval);
                    }
                    else if (firstval>secondval)
                    {
                        return("[0] > [1]"); Convert.ToString(firstval); Convert.ToString(secondval);
                    }
                    else if (firstval==secondval)
                    {
                        return ("[0] = [1]"); Convert.ToString(firstval); Convert.ToString(secondval);
                    }
                    break;
               default:
                        return ("Invalid Entry, please try again.");
                    break;
            }
           return ("Invalid Entry, please try again.");
        }

    private bool ValEntry(string entry)
    {
        for (int p = 0; p < entry.Length; p++)


           if (char.IsDigit(entry[p]))
           {
               return true;
           }
            else if ((entry[p] == '+') || (entry[p] == '-') || (entry[p] == '*') || (entry[p] == '/') || (entry [p] == '%') || (entry [p] == '^') || (entry[p] == '?'))
           {
                return true;
           }
           else
           {
                return false;
           }
       return false;
    }


        private int findoperator (string oploc)
        {

            for (int loc = 0; loc < oploc.Length; loc++)
            {
              if (!char.IsDigit(oploc[loc])) return loc;
            }
            return -1; 
        }


    }
}
} // Moving this to where it belongs shows the error in the location of the }.
```

I'm trying to create a calculator that validates user input, and then runs a calculation with the user input. The program keeps telling me that it needs a type of namespace definition or end of file expected and that I need a curly brace. I looked and each curly brace has a partner and as far as I can see it looks like all of my instances reside within the class.  I'm only two weeks into my programming courses, so please forgive me if I sound like a beginner. I've been working on this for two days and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. If you know what I'm doing wrong, please explain. I've put a bunch of "/" next to where the computer is telling me I need another curly brace.

Comment: The edit I made to your code points out the extra } at the end.

Comment: I have posted a complete code sample. Let us know how you get on and don't forget to mark one of the answers!

Answer (score 3):

Your Main method is not being closed before it moves onto `private string Calculate()`. There should be another } after the end of the `while`. Then you'll just need to remove one of the `}` at the end of the document.

Comment: This changes my errors to a bunch of warnings that say unreachable code.  Should I worry about this?

Comment: I'd imagine it's pointing at your `return ("Invalid Entry, please try again.");` line after your switch statement. Because every case in the switch returns, and you have a return in a default, it will never get to that final `return`. Also, if you are returning, you do not need a `break;` because again, it will not get past that `return` above it.

Comment: Also, your `ValEntry()` method won't get past the if/else if/else statements to that bottom `return false;`. And you do realize that with a `return` in each step of that if/else if/else, you'll only ever process that first character in the input string?

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a closing bracket } just after the end of your while loop.

Try this:

```
namespace Calculator
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program calc = new Program();
            Program validate = new Program();
            bool valid = true;

            while (valid == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Supported functions are *, /, +, -, ^, %.");
                Console.WriteLine("If you would like to find the greater number separate the numbers with a '?'");
                String userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                valid = validate.ValEntry(userInput);

                Console.WriteLine(calc.Calculate(userInput));
            } /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }

        private string Calculate(string input)
        {
            int opstringloc = findoperator(input);
            int firstval = int.Parse(input.Substring(0, opstringloc));
            int secondval = int.Parse(input.Substring(0, opstringloc));
            char operation = Convert.ToChar(input.Substring(opstringloc));


            switch (operation)
            {
                case '+':
                    return Convert.ToString(firstval + secondval);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    return Convert.ToString(firstval - secondval);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    return Convert.ToString(firstval/secondval);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    return Convert.ToString(firstval*secondval);
                    break;
                case '%':
                    return Convert.ToString(firstval%secondval);
                    break;
                case '^':
                    return Convert.ToString(firstval ^ secondval);
                    break;
                case '?':
                    if (firstval < secondval)
                    {
                        return ("[0] < [1]");
                        Convert.ToString(firstval);
                        Convert.ToString(secondval);
                    }
                    else if (firstval > secondval)
                    {
                        return ("[0] > [1]");
                        Convert.ToString(firstval);
                        Convert.ToString(secondval);
                    }
                    else if (firstval == secondval)
                    {
                        return ("[0] = [1]");
                        Convert.ToString(firstval);
                        Convert.ToString(secondval);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return ("Invalid Entry, please try again.");
                    break;
            }
            return ("Invalid Entry, please try again.");
        }

        private bool ValEntry(string entry)
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < entry.Length; p++)


                if (char.IsDigit(entry[p]))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if ((entry[p] == '+') || (entry[p] == '-') || (entry[p] == '*') || (entry[p] == '/') ||
                         (entry[p] == '%') || (entry[p] == '^') || (entry[p] == '?'))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            return false;
        }


        private int findoperator(string oploc)
        {

            for (int loc = 0; loc < oploc.Length; loc++)
            {
                if (!char.IsDigit(oploc[loc])) return loc;
            }
            return -1;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't counted correctly. One after

```
Console.WriteLine(calc.Calculate(userInput));
```

and remove one at the end.

Then I'd just change String to string. And much more probably...